# Не работают медиа запросы css

Tags: css, media-queries

Медиа запрос работает на компьютере: Уменьшаю и увеличиваю ширину окна браузера - всё изменяется. А на телефоне не работает. 
Вот ссылка fegonik.000webhostapp.com

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987)

Comment: теперь всё, добавил

Comment: @Егор если вы невнимательно прочитали предыдущий комментарий: ссылку на проблемый сайт давать **нельзя**. Весь код, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы, должен присутствовать **прямо в тексте вопроса** без ссылок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мобильные браузеры отображают страницы в виртуальном «окне» (viewport, вьюпорт), которое, как правило, шире экрана устройства. Поэтому им не нужно сжимать макет каждой страницы в крошечное окно (что может сломать многие сайты, не оптимизированные под мобильные устройства).

Что бы масштаб страницы соответствовал реальному размеру окна добавьте в заголовок:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```